# SFML: How to check if a point is contained in a group of transformed drawables

Tags: c++, sfml

## Context

I have a class representing a text box. the text box contains a header, some text and a rectangle to enclose the box. It only displays itself (for now):

```cpp
struct Textbox : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable{
  sf::Text header;
  sf::Text text;
  sf::RectangleShape border;

  Textbox(){
    // set relative locations of the members
    header.setPosition(0,0);
    auto header_bounds = header.getGlobalBounds();
    // the text should be just below the header
    text.setPosition(0, header_bounds.top + header_bounds.height);
    auto source_bounds = text.getGlobalBounds();

    // this function just returns a rectangle enclosing two rectangles
    sf::FloatRect rect = enclosing_rect(header_bounds, source_bounds);
    // this function sets the position, width and length of border to be equal to rect's.
    setRectParams(border, rect);
  }

  void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states){
    states.transform = getTransform();
    target.draw(header,states);
    target.draw(text,states);
    target.draw(border,states);
};
```

## The Problem

### What I want

I want to add a `contains` method. It should return true if `coor` is inside the border of the box. Here is my naive implementation:

```cpp
bool Textbox::contains(sf::Vector2i coor) const {
  return border.getGlobalBounds().contains(coor.x, coor.y);
}
```

### Why this implementation doesn't work

This implementation breaks when I move the `Textbox` via the `Transformable` non-virtual functions. The `Textbox` moves and it also draws the shapes as transformed. But! It does not actually transform them! it only displays them as transformed. So the `border` doesn't even know it has been moved.

## Possible solutions

1. I can add all the functions of the `Transformable` API to this class, thus shadowing them and calling transform by myself on each of the members. I don;t like this because it make me write sooo much more code than I wanted. It also raises the question of how to tackle the double transforms (the one for the Textbox and the others for it's members).
2. I can write a completely different class `Group` that holds a vector of `drawable`s and `transformable`s and **it** has all that shadowing API mechanism. All that is left is to inherit from it. This doesn't actually sound **that** bad.
3. I heard about Entity System Component - it's just sound pretty overkill.
4. I can apply the transform when `contains` is called. The function is const - it's a query. Also, it's bad design to update your data on seemingly random calls.
5. just as before just that the transform applies to a function-local rectangle. This smells too - why do I call the transform functions on the whole `Textbox` just so it would apply them on every method call (so far just it's `draw` and `contains` but down the line who knows)
6. Make the members `mutable` and somehow transform them inside the draw method. This smell hackish.

## The question

How do I group transformations onto multiple entities via an ergonomic API?

Answer (score 0):

The only method that you really need to 'change', but to be fair add on your own is `getGlobalBounds()`.

When you are inheriting from `sf::Transformable`, `sf::Drawable` you should treat the base class (your Textbox struct) as a shape itself therfore you just need to call `myTextbox.getGlobalBounds().contains(x,y)`, where `myTextbox` is a `Textbox`.

Using your own code:

```
struct Textbox : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable{
    sf::Text header;
    sf::Text text;
    sf::RectangleShape border;

sf::FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const {
    auto header_bounds = header.getGlobalBounds();
    auto source_bounds = text.getGlobalBounds();

    sf::FloatRect rect = enclosing_rect(header_bounds, source_bounds);
    //Don't really know what it does but let say that it returns Top and Left as 0, and calculates Height, Width.
    return sf::FloatRect(getPosition(), sf::Vector2f(rect.width,rect.height));
    }
};
```

But you still have to manage the rotation, resizing,etc. when calculating globalBounds.

**EDIT:**

One way to implement rotation and scaling.

```
sf::FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const {
    auto header_bounds = header.getGlobalBounds();
    auto source_bounds = text.getGlobalBounds();

    sf::FloatRect rect = enclosing_rect(header_bounds, source_bounds);
    //Don't really know what it does but let say that it returns Top and Left as 0, and calculates Height, Width.
    sf::RectangleShape textbox(sf::Vector2f(rect.width, rect.height));
    //at this point textbox = globalBounds of Textbox without transformations
    textbox.setOrigin(getOrigin());//setOrigin (point of transformation) before transforming
    textbox.setScale(getScale());
    textbox.setRotation(getRotation());
    textbox.setPosition(getPosition());
    //after transformation get the bounds
    return textbox.getGlobalBounds();
}
```

Comment: The transformations that I call on the ```Textbox``` object still don't apply to the members. So ```getGobalBounds``` would return the unchanged enclosing rectangle of the members.

Comment: Yes, because you don't need to change the properties of members since they are all relative to the textbox itself, unless you want to change members one by one, which would require to change them manually I mean changing them relative to the textbox.

Comment: and we can do ```return sf::FloatRect(getPosition(), sf::Vector2f(rect.width * getScale(), rect.height * getScale());``` to take scaling into account too, right? but still, I'm emulating the movement as if it had happened, I'm not sure if this would scale(pun not intended) as the demands for this project pile up.

Comment: However, the `getGlobalBounds` would return the correct `FloatRect` since it calulates the enclosing rectangle relative to `Textbox` `[0,0,width,height]` and then translates it to the world cords by setting the `Top` and `Left` to the position of `Textbox` **(`Textbox` origin must be [0,0])**.

Comment: Well you don't need to scale it inside of calulating the rect. It would be easier to then make a `sf::RectangleShape` out of that `FloatRect` so you don't have to worry about writing our own rotation/scaling code, and only then returing the globalBounds of that `RectangleShape` after you call `rectangleShape.setRotation(getRotation())` etc..

Comment: This is overkill... if you want your own `getGlobalBounds` you can just `return this->getTransform().transformRect(border.getGlobalBounds());`. However, this will still not work if you rotate the text box, because global bounds of a rotated shape (even with your code) contain points out of the shape itself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be much more simple than you expect. Instead of applying all the transforms to the transformable children/members, just *de-transform* the point you want to check (take it to local space).

Try this:

```cpp
bool Textbox::contains(sf::Vector2i coor) const {
  // Get point in the local space of the rectangle
  sf::Transform inverseTr = this->getInverseTransform();
  sf::Vector2f pointAsLocal = inverseTr.transformPoint(coor.x, coor.y);
  
  // Check if the point, now in local space, is containted in the rectangle
  return border.getLocalBounds().contains(pointAsLocal);
  //            ^
  //            Important! Use local bounds here, not global
}
```

**Why does this work?**

Math!

When you work with transformation matrices, you can think of them as portals between spaces. You have a **local space** where no transformation have been applied, and you have a **final space**, where all transformations are applied.

The **problem with global bounds** of a transformable member is that they belong neither to the local space nor the final space. They are just a rectangle bounding the shape in a possibly intermediate space where this bounds doesn't even take rotation into account.

What we are doing here is **taking the coordinates, that exist in the final space, and take them to the local space of the rectangle**, thanks to the **inverse transformation matrix**. So no matter how many translations, rotations or scales (or even skews, if you have customized the matrix) you apply to the rectangle. The inverse matrix takes the point to a new space where you can just check if it belongs, as if no transformation have ever been applied.

Comment: Still I'll pay the cost of transforming on every call to the function. and in the future if ill want a function ```getsize``` or ```intersects``` i would will need do a forward transform to my border member.

Comment: The cost of transforming is very, very low, you could do it thousands of times per frame and won't notice it. About the `getsize` or `intersects`... you didn't mention that. In the `getsize` case, you can just get the `borders.width * getScale().x * borders.height * getScale().y`. For the `intersects`... it depends on the shape you want to intersect with.